# Trying to store the output of file command into a variable , but the output says "no such file exists"?

Tags: linux, shell-script

This is my shell script:

```
$EXTENSION=$(file $RADIOOUT)
```

`$RADIOOUT` contains the file name along with its path.

output is:

```
./zenityentry: line 40: =/home/jeevan/Downloads/p.txt:: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Probably the file `/home/jeevan/Downloads/p.txt` doesn't exist

Comment: @UVV hi, no the file is there. the mistake is = sign at the beginning of the path. how to avoid it??

Comment: You don't include a `$` when defining variables, try this: `EXTENSION=$(file ....)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the leading `$` (and while we're at it, quote `$RADIOOUT` and avoid its being interpreted as an option to `file` if it starts with `-`):

```
EXTENSION=$(file -- "$RADIOOUT")
```